# PHP change anything that is not a letter or a number to `%20`

Tags: php, regex

I need to use PHP to change anything that is not a letter or a number to `%20`.

For example: `$_POST['name'] = "John_Doe"` or `$_POST['name'] = "John-Doe"` would become `John Doe`.

Is there some regex that can be used that would replace anything that is not a letter or a number?

Comment: It is trivial regex, have you tried anything?

Comment: so you want to butcher my real hyphenated name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luis answer is good although it can be written easier

`preg_replace('#\W#', '%20', 'Hello World');`

does the same :) and it's much shorter

`\W` stands for a non-word character

Comment: good one, didn't remember the shortcut

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', '%20', 'Hello World');
```

You'll get

```
"Hello%20World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do this. 
1) You can do a simple replace.

```
   preg_replace('/[^a-zA-z0-9]/', '%20', $YourString);
   //Which should replace anything other then a-Z or 0-9 with '%20'
```

The Documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Or you can brute force it. By running through the string and checking each character to see if it's a letter or a number and replacing that char with `'%20'`

The first way is simpler but the second one is a good exercise